# How do I create a list from embedded Lists in an object in C#

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0

I have something like this:

```
class Movie
{
    public string Title;
    public List<string> Genres = new List<string>();
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> genreList = new List<string();
        genreList.Add("Crime");
        genreList.Add("Thriller");
    var movies = new List<Movie>();
    movies.Add(new Movie { Title = "Pulp Fiction", Genres = genreList });

    genre.List.Clear();
    genrelist.Add("Adventure");
    genrelist.Add("Sci-Fi");
    movies.Add(new Movie { Title = "Back to the Future" Genres = genreList });

    genre.List.Clear();
    genrelist.Add("Adventure");
    genrelist.Add("Crime");
    genrelist.Add("Sci-Fi");
    movies.Add(new Movie { Title = "The Dark Knight", Genres = genreList });
}
```

How can I query the movies List to get a list of all of the genres within the Genres variables?  I want the output to be:
Adventure
Crime
Sci-Fi
Thriller

Thanks as always!

Comment: `genreList.Clear` will infact clear the entries in the previous `movie.Genres` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

movies.SelectMany(m => m.Genres).Distinct();
```

Also, note Cybernate's comment about all the movies having the same list. Try initializing like,

```
movies.Add(new Movie { 
   Title = "Pulp Fiction",
   Genres = { "Crime", "Thriller" } // calls Add on existing List
});
// or
// assign a copy of genreList
genreList.Clear();
genrelist.Add("Adventure");
genrelist.Add("Sci-Fi");
movies.Add(new Movie { Title = "Back to the Future", Genres = genreList.ToList() });
```